# Magento 2.3.5 Content Security Policy CSP for Worker

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, csp, content-security-policy

I was really annoyed by the lack of documentation around the following console errors showing up.

```
[Report Only] Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https://domain.com/535c516f-8a3a-4d17-b0c0-a207e461f42c' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "worker-src ".
```

Nowhere I found any information on how to solve it. There is documentation on the content security policy and although its report only its no harm but still irritating.

Answer (score 1):

So after some trial and error, I just solved it.

I personally always have a custom `baseconfig` module in app/code/ so for example `/app/code/sitename/baseconfig` where i force set certain settings in core_config. so ideal for this kind of stuff. in the etc folder of that module, I added a file called `csp_whitelist.xml` which is also very clearly documented on Magento devdocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

In that file i added the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="worker-src">
            <values>
                <value id="worker-blob" type="host">blob:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```